# Is there an adjective that means of or pertaining to a cloud/ cloud-like?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective that means of or pertaining to a cloud in the way that nebular might refer to nebulas?

For example, the candy floss appeared (cloud-like??)

Comment: Is there some reason you refuse "cloudlike" or "cloud-like", which are in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloudlike) both with and without hyphen?

Comment: 'nebulous' is the obvious version (see EAs answer). But that is more synonomous with 'cloudy' (as in vague) as opposed to looking like cotton-candy poofed-up big white cotton ball. 'puffy'? or simile-adjectives (?) 'cloud-like' or 'marshmallow-like'?

Comment: A nebula is a cloud — a space cloud. So *nebular* works fine. I would say: _The candy floss **was** nebular._

Comment: @StuartF In short, no. I simply wondered if there was an alternative. Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

> **nebulous** [adjective]:
>
> in the form of a cloud or haze; hazy.

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nebulous)]

However, neither 'The candy floss appeared cloud-like' nor 'The candy floss appeared nebulous' are stylistically wonderful. 'The candy floss appeared like a wispy pink cloud' is perhaps better, but saccharine.

And I'll be honest, I'm not happy with Lexico putting the prototypical sense before the more commonly used one (hazy, vague, indistinct, or confused: [R H K Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nebulous) //  lacking definite form, shape, or content; vague or amorphous ... *nebulous reasons*: [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nebulous)).

Comment: +1  ...  *but saccharine*...   ;-)

Comment: Anyone reading this with "nebulous" would understand it to be hazy, indistinct.

Comment: @Edwin Thank you! I hadn't considered nebulous for the very reason that it has a far more familiar meaning. As a word it does seem to suggest the hazy, more indefinable boundaries of a cloud rather than the bulky mass of more cumulous clouds! Perhaps cumulous, if a little technical, was the word I was looking for!